# How to write a search template in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm writing a searcher that is supposed to find persons by first name or last name.

There is a table

```
persons:
id    first_name    last_name
 1    Robert        Krone
```

And a query

```
select * from persons as p where concat(p.first_name, p.last_name) like '% variable %'
```

When I'm trying to find a person like Krone Ro.. - it does not work. How to make it to work in both directions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try adding  an OR clause  for inverted  columns

```
select * from persons as p 
where concat(p.first_name, p.last_name) like '% variable %' 
OR  concat(p.last_name, p.first_name) like '% variable %'
```

or

```
select * from persons as p 
where concat(p.first_name, p.last_name) like concat('%',variable,'0%') 
OR  concat(p.last_name, p.first_name) like concat('%',variable, '%')
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below Query and it should be work and maybe you don't need to do concat for this.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  PERSONS AS P
WHERE
  P.FIRST_NAME LIKE '%Ro%'
  OR P.FIRST_NAME LIKE '%Ro%';
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to split the search string by spaces and validate that each component appears in one or more names.  To do this, I suggest the following approach:

- Split the search string by spaces.
- Check each component against the names.
- Count the number of matches.
- Make sure all components are matched.

Assuming that the components of the string are unique, you can use:

```
select p.*
from persons p
where (select count(distinct ss.ss)
       from (values (p.first_name), (p.last_name)) v(name) join
            regexp_split_to_table(?, ' ') ss
            on v.name like '%' || ss.ss || '%'
      ) = (select count(*) from regexp_split_to_table(?, ' '))
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=6623794f8f990b4e7f2a43c5c3e4059a) is a db<>fiddle.

Although this is possible using strings, I would advise you to consider other options.

- Allow the users to use regular expressions on concatenated columns.  These are very powerful.  So, although they don't do exactly what you want, the added functionality might be helpful.
- Split the search terms into an array and pass the array into the query.
- Use full-text search.